# using supervisord for running multiple php instances however running tasks half that

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, supervisord

I am using supervisord within a docker container(s) to run multiple instances of a php script. The purpose of the script is it scrapes data from a webpage. I have the number of processes in the config file set to 75 and it loads all of these fine. However when i run "top" or "htop" its only showing between 15-25 give or take are running. I can see on "top" a list of them all, and can confirm they are starting but some have R and other have S which changes as i monitor them.

Have tried reducing the instances to a single php script running, and scale the number of containers in docker from 1 to 75.

```
[program:collector]
priority = 100
numprocs=75
process_name = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command = /bin/bash -c "/bin/sleep 2 && /usr/bin/php collector.php"
directory=/var/www/dev
environment=GEARMAN_USER=gearman
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/program_phpworker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/program_phpworker.error
startsecs = 5
autorestart = true
```

My expectations would be if i request 75 instances of the same script to run i would see all 75 running.

Comment: Unless you have a machine with 75+ CPUs how would you expect to have 75+ processes running simultaneously? Of course most of them are going to be in the **S**leep state, and even if they weren't your machine would most likely be horrifyingly overloaded.

Comment: If they're all blocked on HTTP GETs that's not actually unreasonable, but I would definitely scale this by running one process per container (and ditching supervisord) and running many copies of it.

Comment: @Sammitch your reply makes no sense what so ever, i have 4 core cpu so based on your logic i could only run 4 php scripts."Yes multiple processes can run simultaneously (without context-switching) in multi-core processors. If all processes are single threaded as you ask then 2 processes can run simultaneously in a dual core processor."

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your input, i will look at scrapping that and going to 1 per container. My plan was to use docker swam across my 3 machines for better scaling of containers. I think i only originally used supervisord as it was recommend to keep the container alive for the php scripts, and then i knew you could have it load multiple instance from before i used docker. Regarding the HTTP GETs could they be blocked due to IO limitation?